# Partial View in MVC 3.1 getting error on Model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model, asp.net-core-mvc

I am new to .net core and creating a page with a partial view

my main page

```
some html here
@*<partial name="~/Pages/Shared/_HomeBanners.cshtml" for="Input.StringProprty" />*@
@await Html.PartialAsync("~/Pages/Shared/_HomeBanners.cshtml", Model.Input.StringProprty)
some html here
```

from main page, I am calling _HomeBanners.cshml and passing a string and on the _HomeBanners.cshtml I have this code

```
@page
@*@model List<Website.Core.Models.BannerInfo>*@
@model string

<h1>Count = @Model</h1>
```

I am getting error
[image]

currently, it is just a string  but later will replace it with a collection of objects which I already have on main page @Model.Info.Banners of list type
Code behind of the partial view is just standard, I did not write anything in that.

as per [this example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/partial?view=aspnetcore-3.1) it should just work but don't know what I am missing.

I would like to use partial view something like this

```
@await Html.PartialAsync("~/Pages/Shared/_HomeBanners.cshtml")
```

so all the logic to display data from the database can go inside partial view, this is what we used to do in asp.net forms user control.

Comment: Do include your controller code or view code that calls and passes a model to the view/partial view.

Comment: I am not taking anything from controller, just passing a hard coded string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please note that the partial page does not feature an `@page` directive. To fix the issue, you can remove the `@page` directive from the content of `_HomeBanners.cshtml` page.

_HomeBanners.cshtml page

```
@model string

<h1>Count = @Model</h1>
```

Main page

```
@page
@model YourPageModel


@await Html.PartialAsync("~/Pages/Shared/_HomeBanners.cshtml", "125")
```

Test Result

[image]